# moving struct from end of one list to start of another list

Tags: c, list, pointers, structure, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to write two functions: One that pushes out the last cell of a list, and another one to make that cell the first one in another list. Somehow, my functions don't work (and I've checked the other parts of my code many times).

```
void last_cell_out(CellPtr list, CellPtr c)
{
    if (list==NULL)/*if list is empty*/
        return;/*doing nothing*/
    if (list->next==NULL)/*if theres only one cell in the list*/
    {
        c=list;
        list=NULL;
        return;/*deleting from list and moving to c*/
    }
    if (list->next->next==NULL)
    {
        c=list->next;
        list->next=NULL;
    }
    else
        last_cell_out(list->next, c);
    return;
}

CellPtr new_first_cell(CellPtr list, CellPtr c)
{
    c->next=list;
    return c;/*returnes the start of the list*/
}
```

Comment: your problem seems to be that you think that by changing the value of c inside the first function, you are changing the value outside of it as well, that is not true. If you want to "obtain" the value of the last cell removed by last_cell_out, you have to either return the value or use a parameter that's a pointer and assign to it's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function seems perfectly fine to me, given how you described your requirements

```
CellPtr new_first_cell(CellPtr list, CellPtr c)
{
    c->next=list;
    return c;/*returnes the start of the list*/
}
```

However the `last_cell_out` has some problems.

first of all you don't need this block of code

```
if (list->next->next==NULL)
{
    c=list->next;
    list->next=NULL;
}
```

it would be dealt with in the next cycle anyway.

That being said your function does remove the last element from the list.
It just does not return it or change it in your code in a way that you can see that.

One option would be to return the last cell, instead of passing it as a parameter.

```
CellPtr last_cell_out(CellPtr *listPtr)
{
    CellPtr list = *listPtr;
    if (list==NULL)/*if list is empty*/
        return NULL;/*doing nothing*/
    if (list->next==NULL)/*if theres only one cell in the list*/
    {
        *listPtr = NULL;
        return list;/*deleting from list and return*/
    }
    return last_cell_out(&(list->next));
}
```

The second variant would pass the c as a pointer so you can change it's contents inside the code.

```
void last_cell_out(CellPtr *listPtr, CellPtr *c)
{
    CellPtr list = *listPtr;
    if (list==NULL)/*if list is empty*/
    {
        *c = NULL;
        return;/*doing nothing*/
    }
    if (list->next==NULL)/*if theres only one cell in the list*/
    {
        *c=list;
        *listPtr = NULL;
        return;/*deleting from list and moving to c*/
    }
    last_cell_out(&((*listPtr)->next), c);
    return;
}
```

You can also completely avoid recursion to avoid a possible stack overflow if your list becomes too large.

```
CellPtr last_cell_out(CellPtr *listPtr)
{
    CellPtr list = *listPtr;
    if(list == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(list->next == NULL) {
        *listPtr = NULL;
        return list;
    }

    while(list->next->next != NULL)
        list = list->next;

    CellPtr tmp = list->next;
    list->next = NULL;
    return tmp;
}
```

Complete test program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct cell *CellPtr;
typedef struct cell
{
    int contents; /* contents of the cell */
    CellPtr next; /* next cell in the list */
} Cell;

CellPtr last_cell_out(CellPtr *listPtr)
{
    CellPtr list = *listPtr;
    if(list == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(list->next == NULL) {
        *listPtr = NULL;
        return list;
    }

    while(list->next->next != NULL)
        list = list->next;

    CellPtr tmp = list->next;
    list->next = NULL;
    return tmp;
}

CellPtr new_first_cell(CellPtr list, CellPtr c)
{
    c->next=list;
    return c;/*returnes the start of the list*/
}

void show_list(CellPtr list)
{
    if(list == NULL) {
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("%d ", list->contents);
    show_list(list->next);
}

int main()
{
    CellPtr list = NULL;
    CellPtr out;
    int i;

    show_list(list);

    CellPtr elem = malloc(sizeof(struct cell));
    elem->contents = 0;
    list = new_first_cell(list, elem);

    show_list(list);

    out = last_cell_out(&list);
    show_list(list);
    list = new_first_cell(list, out);
    show_list(list);

    for(i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
        CellPtr elem = malloc(sizeof(struct cell));
        elem->contents = i;
        list = new_first_cell(list, elem);
    }

    show_list(list);
    out = last_cell_out(&list);
    show_list(list);
    list = new_first_cell(list, out);
    show_list(list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `last_cell_out` has to accept its arguments by reference because it changes their original values. Otherwise the function will have undeifined behaviour because for example this statement

```
list=NULL;
```

does not changes the original value of the list. It only changes its local variable `list` defined as a parameter that has a copy of the vlaue of the original list.

So the function should be defined at least the following way

```
void last_cell_out(CellPtr *list, CellPtr *c)
{
    if ( *list == NULL )/*if list is empty*/
    {
        *c = NULL;
        return;/*doing nothing*/
    }        
    else if ( ( *list )->next == NULL )/*if theres only one cell in the list*/
    {
        *c = *list;
        *list = NULL;
        return;/*deleting from list and moving to c*/
    }
    else if ( ( *list )->next->next == NULL )
    {
        *c = ( *list )->next;
        ( *list )->next = NULL;
        return;/*deleting from list and moving to c*/
    }
    else
    {
        last_cell_out( &( *list )->next, c );
        return;/*doing nothing*/
    }        
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Cell
{
    int data;
    struct Cell *next;
};

typedef struct Cell *CellPtr;

void last_cell_out(CellPtr *list, CellPtr *c)
{
    if ( *list == NULL )/*if list is empty*/
    {
        *c = NULL;
        return;/*doing nothing*/
    }        
    else if ( ( *list )->next == NULL )/*if theres only one cell in the list*/
    {
        *c = *list;
        *list = NULL;
        return;/*deleting from list and moving to c*/
    }
    else if ( ( *list )->next->next == NULL )
    {
        *c = ( *list )->next;
        ( *list )->next = NULL;
        return;/*deleting from list and moving to c*/
    }
    else
    {
        last_cell_out( &( *list )->next, c );
        return;/*doing nothing*/
    }        
}

CellPtr new_first_cell(CellPtr list, CellPtr c)
{
    c->next = list;
    return c;/*returnes the start of the list*/
}

void print_cells( CellPtr list )
{
    for ( CellPtr current = list; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->data );
    }

    puts( "NULL" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    CellPtr list = NULL;

    CellPtr cell = malloc( sizeof( struct Cell ) );
    cell->data = 1;

    list = new_first_cell( list, cell );

    print_cells( list );

    last_cell_out( &list, &cell );

    CellPtr list1 = NULL;

    list1 = new_first_cell( list1, cell );

    print_cells( list );
    print_cells( list1 );

    last_cell_out( &list1, &cell );

    free( cell );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 -> NULL
NULL
1 -> NULL
```

Take into account that it is a bad idea to use a typedef for a pointer because it  sometimes confuses users.

And the function `last_cell_out` can be written simpler without recursion. For example

```
void last_cell_out(CellPtr *list, CellPtr *c)
{
    if ( *list )
    {
        while ( ( *list )->next ) list = &( *list )->next;
    }

    *c = *list;
    *list = NULL;
}
```

Or with recursion

```
void last_cell_out(CellPtr *list, CellPtr *c)
{
    if ( *list && ( *list )->next )
    {
        last_cell_out( &( *list )->next, c );
    }
    else
    {
        *c = *list;
        *list = NULL;
    }       
}
```